# angular change css class on firestore event

Tags: css, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i would like to change a css class when data updates from firestore received. To do so i tried the following:

```
this.afs.collection('orders').doc(this.data.id).valueChanges().subscribe(dataset => {
  console.log(dataset.state);
  this.state = dataset.state;
  this.takeAway = dataset.takeaway;
});
```

and here is my html:

```
  <div class="progress dark">
<div class="right">
  <div [ngClass]="{'current': this.state === 'submitted'}">Übermittelt</div>
  <div [ngClass]="{'current': this.state === 'cooking'}">In Zubereitung</div>
  <div *ngIf="!takeAway" [ngClass]="{'current': this.state === 'delivery'}">In Zustellung</div>
  <div  *ngIf="takeAway" [ngClass]="{'current': this.state === 'ready'}">Bereit zur Abholung</div>
  <div class="done" [ngClass]="{'current': this.state === 'done'}">Gericht erhalten</div>
</div>
```

the problem is if i call my component the first time, everything is working but if data has changed, nothing is going to happen. I defineteley receive the data so the error is how to bind the dynamic class

Comment: You don't need `this.` in html. After that I would simply print the state just to see what value it holds `{{state}}`.

Comment: you are right, the value in my html is never updated. Do you know why?

Comment: I would check the snippet you posted first, `valueChanges().subscribe....` is it executed? If so what you have inside `dataset.state`?

Comment: @DominikHartl any progress? Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hi @FaridShumbar yes i solved it, i had to add the dependency to my podfile

Comment: @DominikHartl Thanks for sharing. Please also consider posting your solution as the answer to this post so the community would benefit from it.

Comment: sure, sorry @FaridShumbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research i was able to solve the issue. Ionic missed to add one required dependency to my Podfile. Here is the final podfile with all required dependencies and imports:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

def capacitor_pods
  # Automatic Capacitor Pod dependencies, do not delete
   pod 'Capacitor', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
   pod 'CapacitorCordova', :path => '../../node_modules/@capacitor/ios'
   pod 'CordovaPlugins', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
   pod 'CordovaPluginsResources', :path => '../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins'
  # Do not delete
 end

 target 'App' do
 capacitor_pods
 # Add your Pods here

  end
```